# How to play .mp3 file from Amazon Polly text to speech without saving the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, mp3, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I am using Amazon Polly for text to speech, but I don't want to save the converted file to the PC retrieving it. Instead, I want to play it as a stream.

I have used `playsound` but it is not working with the returned variable.

```
client = boto3.client('polly')

output = client.synthesize_speech (
  Text = "Some random text I want to convert", OutputFormat = "mp3", VoiceId = 'Aditi'
)

print(output['AudioStream'])

file = open('speech.mp3', 'wb')
file.write(output['AudioStream'].read())
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pydub`](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) to load the mp3 stream into AudioSegment directly.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(output['AudioStream'])
```

Comment: Then how do you play it?

Comment: Try this on `jupyter-notebook` and you will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to save the file locally you can playback the stream directly using `pyaudio`. Depending on your use case, you can read chunks of stream with defined buffer size or just read the whole stream and play it:

```
import sys
from contextlib import closing

import boto3
import pyaudio
from botocore.exceptions import BotoCoreError, ClientError


session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)
polly = session.client("polly")

SAMPLE_RATE = 16000
READ_CHUNK = 4096
CHANNELS = 1
BYTES_PER_SAMPLE = 2

try:
    response = polly.synthesize_speech(Text="Hello world!",
                                       VoiceId="Joanna",
                                       LanguageCode="en-US",
                                       OutputFormat="pcm",
                                       SampleRate=str(SAMPLE_RATE))

except (BotoCoreError, ClientError) as error:
    print(error)
    sys.exit(-1)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(BYTES_PER_SAMPLE),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=SAMPLE_RATE,
                output=True)

with closing(response["AudioStream"]) as polly_stream:
    while True:
        data = polly_stream.read(READ_CHUNK)
        if data is None:
            break

        stream.write(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```